# Solve equation without using symbolic toolbox in Matlab

Tags: matlab, solution, symbolic-computation

I need to solve this equation for the variable \theta:

[image]

using Matlab WITHOUT using symbolic toolbox. The reason for this is that I am compiling the m-file to .Net Assembly and symbolic toolbox can not be used.

I know how to solve it using `vpasolve`, but as far as I know it needs the variable to be defined using `syms`.

I appreciate if you can suggest me a method to solve this equation in Matlab without symbolic toolbox.

Comment: Are the other variables known *a priori*?  If they're not known, then what you ask for is not possible.

Comment: yes, as I mentioned in my post the only variable is \theta

Comment: The other variables being known *a priori* was not established in your question, which is why I had to ask.  Knowing that they are, the answer by McMa is a perfectly example answer for your application.

Comment: thank you for your comment and sorry for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @rayryeng said, that is only possible if you know the value of the other variables, is so, you can declare f as an anonymous function and use `fsolve()` like this:

```
f=@(x)((cos(x)*sqrt(2^2+3^2)-4*sin(x))/(cos(x)-1)-5/x);
fsolve(f,0.1)
```

but using your correct values.